# window.open compatibility with Mac OSx versions (Safari)

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, window.open

@jackJoe my changes did not resolve my issue here is the rendered HTML for the Image Button and the window.open:

```
   <div id="ctl00_LoginPanel" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_imbSubmit2')" style="width:201px;">
```

I have successfully changed the defaultbutton for the panel when the user is a Safari user. The Image Button also shows up as an input type:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$imbSubmit2" id="ctl00_imbSubmit2" src="../images/Submitbutton.jpg" alt="Submit2" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$imbSubmit2&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

Why doesn't this work in Safari??

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + strURL + "');</script>")
```

Do I need to have it like this:

```
Response.Write("<script>javascript:window.open('" + strURL + "');</script>")
```

Comment: it doesn't matter if it is .aspx, as long as the server isn't a Mac, safari *understands* .aspx. Related to your problem, that's a tough one, could you post the work arround please?

Comment: @jackJoe, I read a post that stated using the script directly would allow for Safari to open the new window using window.open. If it was a call to a function to return the javascript to window.open it would treat it as a pop-up in Safari therfore it would not allow it to open Unless the pop-up blocker is/was turned off. I will try to remove all of the sensitive data from my current code and post it in a little bit. I also read that 'hooking' the window.open to a click_event of a button would allow for it to open as well, but this does not work. I will post code to see if i can get help.

Comment: @jackJoe, Perhaps that post meant that I could place the javascript inline within the aspx page and call it when the button is clicked as opposed to adding it to the aspx.vb code behind...While trying to remove sensitive infor from my code I realized I am still using an additional function within the code to create the URL for the window.open logic. It is just a string builder that i can move into the button_click event to see if it remedies my issue.

Comment: @jackJoe, The BuildURL is a string builder to put together the full URL with some parameters in it. hopefully posting this code will give you a better idea of what I am attempting to do for the Safari user.

Comment: ok, but could you post the rendered html with link (I just need that really), the VB seems ok.

Comment: @jackJoe, just to explain I am using 2 different Submit Buttons within my Master page depending on login. If you are the type Safari then load the second submit button that calls a different click_event. The original Submit button is set as the defaultbutton for the Panel in which it resides. I tried to programatically change the defaultbutton in the page_load event for the Safari user so the <enter> would work. I have added the page_load code and the rendered html for both buttons above. Please take a look.

Comment: I think my issue was the fact that the VB code behind I was changing the form DefaultButton to imbSubmit2.UniqueID instead of changing the Panel DefaultButton to imbSubmit2.UniqueID. the code above was: Page.Master.Page.Form.DefaultButton = imbSubmit2.UniqueID and when I changed it to Panel.DefaultButton = imbSubmit2.UniqueID then the imbSubmit2 rendered correctly.

Comment: does that mean everything is fine?

Comment: @jackJoe, I will have my Mac Safari user test this tonight to see if it works now. Thank you for suggesting I take a look at the rendered HTML....That pointed me to my issue I believe.